# Memory management in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to compute the maximum of an external function with two variables in Fortran. This function is a huge likelihood function and i have to find the bests parameters of the likelihood. 
The problem is that because the function with all the events weights  ~10 Mb , during compilation the compiler returns me segmentation fault. If i compile with few events all works fine. 
How i can overcome the problem of the weight of the external function?

Comment: what compiler and operating system are we talking about here?

Comment: gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

Comment: I would suggest trying an different gcc version -- you probably have found a compiler bug. I doubt anyone will be able to help you resolve this here. You next step is probably preparing a repro case and filing a bug with your distro or upstream with the developers.

Comment: gfortran on i686-linux-gnu based on gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

Comment: @IRO-bot: He is saying the *compiler* is segfaulting during compilation...

Comment: Oh, wow. Should read more carefully. My bad

Comment: 10 MB is nothing on a modern computer with gigabytes of memory.  I suggest providing more information.   Can you narrow down the source code that causes the problem and show it to us?

Answer (score 0):

10 Mb shouldn't present any problem for a function (we are talking a modern computer here, not a 286 or something from that time, right?), but the fact it returns a seg. error hints there is something wrong with the code.

In fortran one doesn't usually get that many seg. faults, so I can only guess what it could be. It would be useful if you could post a part of the code where the error occurs, or try to isolate it to a small example which reproduces the same error.

Comment: The function is 10 Mb weight in a single piece. i.e. 
y=log(a*x+b)* .... *... x 10MB
so i suppose that is a problem of memory management.